# Using Spring Themes Recalls the last Controller method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, themes

I have Spring Themes working, but I have discovered that each time I click on a Theme, it recalls the last Controller command (call).  Is this normal?  If so, how can I avoid this unnecessary call?

Here is a Snippet view of my servlet conf file:

```
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
        </beans:bean>                      
    </mvc:interceptors>



    <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">        
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />       
    </beans:bean>   


    <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="definitions">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
            <beans:property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Any info. will be useful.

Comment: Can you also post your `@Controller`?

Comment: Which is, depending on your view, normal. It will re-render the current page (basically issue the last request again) with a different value for the `theme` parameter. So yes this is normal. If this isn't what you want, you need to modify the form that controls the theme and create a controller which handles the theme switch (it needs to redirect to/render some view).

Comment: @M.Deinum - thanks for your answer - that's what I wanted to know.  If you convert your comment into an answer, I can click the 'tick' icon if you so wish.  Kind regards, Cem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general this is normal, most people put a form around a `select` element, the form has no action specified. Which will lead to issuing the last request to the server again. In general this will result in redoing the last action, including a different value for the `theme` parameter.

If you want to have a different behavior include a default action for the form which changes the theme. You will need to have this backed by a controller which redirects to a page, or for isntance the value of the referrer header.